# How did Valkyrie get to Sakaar?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

What did she fly with? How did she know where to go and why wasn't she also imprisoned as a slave?

Comment: "What did she fly with?" She has a ship of her own in the very first scene we see her in.

Comment: @phantom42 that doesn't mean she had the ship before he self-imposed exile on Sakaar. We don't know the information you're asking, and given you want to know from the film's perspective, we're not going to find out.

Comment: Sure, but you could also say, "well, we don't see Han arrive on Tatooine in the Falcon. How did he get there?" At some point we have to ask if we're overthinking things.

Comment: How is this within the scope of this SE?

Answer (score 2):

> What did she fly with?

We don't know; there's no information about this.  We also don't know how long ago it was - Asgardians live longer than humans, and she's old enough to remember before Hela was imprisoned, so it could have been quite a while.  We don't know if she arrived under her own power or if she came in through a door.  She's on a planet surrounded by doorways, y'know.

> How did she know where to go

Sakaar is where the lost and unloved things go.  From what we saw in her flashback and of her comments, it's pretty clear she felt lost and unloved, and gravitated there.

> and why wasn't she also imprisoned as a slave?

She fights on par with the Hulk and ingratiates better than Loki.  QED.

Comment: I don’t think she fights on par with the Hulk.... I’m not sure even Thor does. She’s certainly a better fighter than most Asgardians, though, who are already superhuman.

Comment: @Adamant I based that on the fact that she shows up with a weapon in hand and Hulk goes off with her saying "Hulk trains."  If she's good enough to spar with the Hulk in training, they've got to be somewhat closely matched; otherwise it wouldn't be useful training for him.

Comment: I think the deal is that she's got much better combat *skill* than the Hulk (she's an elite soldier who's been practicing for millenia, after all, whereas the Hulk is like 50 or something). Especially given that Hulk (understandably) is a little over-reliant on brute force, he can learn a lot. But Hulk is still a lot stronger and more durable, and would almost certainly win a hypothetical real fight. I'm sure she can still spar with Hulk productively though - she's still a top-tier Asgardian, like Thor.